# Google App Engine Deploy AttributeError expat_CAPI

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have been using Google App Engine Launcher many times and it worked perfect but recently I used it and **I had this Error:**

```
2014-01-02 18:50:58 Running command: "[u'C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=[my email]', '--passin', 'update', u'D:\\temp\\my-aiesec']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 196, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 192, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 81, in <module>
    from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bulkloader.py", line 128, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.bulkload import bulkloader_config
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\bulkload\bulkloader_config.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.bulkload import simplexml_connector
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\bulkload\simplexml_connector.py", line 40, in <module>
    from xml.etree import cElementTree as ElementTree
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\xml\etree\cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _elementtree import *
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'expat_CAPI'
2014-01-02 18:50:59 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

1- First I thought the version of my GAE is out dated. so I upgrade to newest version 1.8.8.

2- I set the python 2.7 path in preferences.

3- I created a new project and launched it locally and it worked.

But still I had this deploying problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I defined **PYTHONPATH** in the **Environment Variables** (System Variables) of my windows. I removed that Variable and Google App Engine worked again.